# I can't update mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I built something for my office, PHP CODE

when I built it over my APACHE it worked fine, when I uploaded it to the server I'm getting the POD or MYSQLI errors, I fixed it (by using "error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);" on the top, and it worked)

the only problem that I'm having now is that I can't update the database as I did on my APACHE, it just doesn't update. it give me the OK message but it doesn't update anything.

this is my code:

```
<?php
mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','TABLE');

if(isset($_POST["register"]))
{

$status=$_POST["status"];

mysqli_query("update login set status='$status' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['name_of_user']."'"); 

echo "<font face=tahoma size=3 color=red>Thank you, the office has been updated.</br></font>";

}
mysqli_close($con);
 ?>

 <form method="post" action=" ">
 <font face=tahoma size=3><b>
 <label >Update Status:</label>
</br>
 <select name="status">
 <option value="In a Meeting">In a Meeting</option>
 <option value="Waiting for a Meeting">Waiting for Meeting</option>
 <option value="In a Referral">In a Referral</option>
 <option value="Off Work">Off Work</option>

 </select>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="register" >Send</button>
</br>
</font>
</form>
```

Comment: Assign action value in form tag

Comment: what were the error that you get in your production server ? and can you post the value of var_dump($status)?? Also, please check your data type for status column in your server database (it should'nt be INT) .

Comment: Forget to start session at the top of page!!

Comment: `mysqli_query` appears to be missing the $con variable which should be the first parameter. $con isn't being set anywhere and should come from `mysqli_connect`

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you forgot to start the session in your page

```
<?php 
session_start();
```

and your `mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','TABLE');` should be `mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','your_database_name');`

```
$con =mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','your_database_name');
 mysqli_query($con,"update login set status='$status' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['name_of_user']."'");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply!
i forgot to write that i did start the session on the top of the code (the file is way longer than what i posted, but that's the issue that i'm having right now with it)
I tried to add $con before i started the SQL query (UPDATE) but it still doesn't work for some reason. i can see the OK message that its been updated, but it doesn't update anything

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` appears to be missing the `$con` variable which should be the first parameter. $con isn't being set anywhere and should come from `mysqli_connect` See [the docs for connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and [query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','TABLE');

if(isset($_POST["register"]))
{

    $status=$_POST["status"];

    mysqli_query($con, "update login set status='$status' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['name_of_user']."'"); 

    echo "<font face=tahoma size=3 color=red>Thank you, the office has been updated.</br></font>";

}
mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget to start the session

```
session_start()
```

you have to declare `$con` variable before use it

use this query

```
mysqli_query($con,"update login set status='".$status."' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['name_of_user']."'");
```